# SQL: count emails per year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the amount of mails I send per year in my database.

Ive tried

```
SELECT Distinct year(RCM_DateSent) FROM Mail
ORDER BY RCM_DateSent
```

Also

```
SELECT COUNT(*)AS [Send], RCM_DateSent FROM Mail
GROUP BY RCM_DateSent 
ORDER BY [Send]
```

The result is not what I want, I want to see how may emails was send per year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select year(rcm_dateSent) as yearSent, count(*) as numbersend
from mail
group by year(rcm_dateSent)
order by yearSent
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to 'group by year'. Like this:

```
SELECT Year(RCM_DateSent) AS YearOfMail, count(*) AS TotalMailsSent  
FROM Mail  
GROUP BY Year(RCM_DateSent)  
ORDER BY Year(RCM_DateSent)
```

PS: It is better to use Year(RCM_DateSent) in group by & order by, instead of the alias name.

Comment: why is that better to use Year(RCM_DateSent) in order by instead of the alias name ?

Comment: because of this: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2010/10/03/why-can-t-we-have-column-alias-in-order-by.aspx

Comment: so it is more an opinion than performance ? There is no advanage.